# Zend Framework 2 routing action

Tags: zend-framework2

I've recive an error when run I run "localhost/products/edit" 
what's wrong I have done ? Ofcourse I have function edit in 
Product controller classand edit.html in view.

```
        'products' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/products',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Products',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/products[/:action]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),


'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'Application\Controller\Products' => 'Application\Controller\ProductsController'
    )

),
```

);

Comment: What is the error message? And probably worth posting a striped down controller if you can.

Comment: "A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
No Exception available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your child roots array:

```
'child_routes' => array(
                                        'view' => array(
                                                    'type' => 'segment',
                                                    'options' => array(
                                                            'route'    => '/:id',
                                                            'constraints' => array(
                                                                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                                            ),
                                                            'defaults' => array(
                                                                    'action'     => 'view',
                                                            ),
                                                        ),
                                                    'may_terminate' => true,
                                                    'child_routes' => array(

                                                            'actions' => array(
                                                                    'type' => 'segment',
                                                                    'options' => array(
                                                                            'route'    => '/:action',
                                                                            'constraints' => array(
                                                                                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                                                            ),
                                                                            'defaults' => array(
                                                                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\ProductsController,
                                                                                    'action'     => 'view',                                                                             ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                ), 
                                                    ),
                                        ),
                            ),
```

Also it needs to be localhost/products/[:id]/edit like localhost/products/1/edit not localhost/products/edit I would imagine anyway but I don't know what your doing to be fair. Just remove the id parameter and constraint and it should work

Notice child root actions do not have the route repeated as it is inherited... your route would create something like /products/products/edit

Comment: ok now I have in child route => /:action , works fine :) bu in view file using echo $this->url('products', array('action'=>'edit')); return only /products/ :(

Comment: $this->url('products/actions', array('action'=>'edit'));

Comment: But you need to update default to actions as in my example or it will be $this->url('products/default', array('action'=>'edit')); maybe

Comment: Compare line under child_routes in your code and my example code and you should see what I mean

Comment: unfortunately ... I got an error: Route with name "actions" not found

Comment: Did you update name of the route to actions instead of default?

Comment: Awesome! That's what I like to hear :)